# How to avoid auxiliary predicates?

Tags: prolog, refactoring, higher-order-functions

I wrote the following code for transposing (finite) lists of (finite) lists (leveraging enough laziness in Prolog for infinite cases eludes me so far):

```
transpose_opt([],[]) :- !.
transpose_opt(L,M) :-
  maplist(go,L,C,R),
  step(C,R,M).
go([],none,[]).
go([H|T],some(H),T).
step(C,_,[]) :- list_to_set(C,[none]), !.
step(C,R,[C|S]) :- transpose_opt(R,S).

transpose(L,M) :-
  transpose_opt(L,O),
  maplist(
    [X,Y]>>(
      maplist([X,Y]>>(X=..[_|Y]),X,V),
      append(V,Y)
    ),O,M).
```

It works, but it seems to me those auxiliary predicates `go` and `step` could be inlined. Any suggestions how?

I tried the following with step unsuccessfully (results in unifying M with a singleton of an unboud variable):

```
transpose_opt([],[]) :- !.
transpose_opt(L,M) :-
  maplist(go,L,C,R),
  forall(member(X,C),X=none) ->
    M=[], !;
    transpose(R,S), M=[C|S], !.
```

(For some reason I don't fathom the check with `forall` and `member` works in the condition but the simpler `list_to_set` doesn't.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> results in unifying M with a singleton of an unboud variable

Try instead:

```
transpose_opt(L,M) :-
  maplist(go,L,C,R),
  (   forall(member(X,C),X=none) ->
      M=[]
  ;   transpose(R,S), M=[C|S]
  ),
  !.
```

Comment: Oh, so it's an operator precedence thing, the `maplist(go,L,C,R)` was being included in the predecessor of `->`. Totally makes sense that it's an implicant.

Btw, my 2 `!` are unnecessary and instead of `transpose` there should be a recursive call of `transpose_opt` (but not editing my post to avoid creating discrepancy with your answer).